# Date format in HTML cfgrid or SQL date format

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am trying to format dates in an HTML cfgrid. I cannot seem to make it work in CF when using HTML as the grid type. I have also tried doing it in MSSQL by using - CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), startDate, 101) AS startDate.

When I do that it shows up right in the grid but the grid will not sort on the date properly.

I understand why converting it to varchar screws up the sort but I cannot seem to make this work in either CF or SQL.

Anyone know of a way to make it show up in the grid in a mm/dd/yyyy format and also sort on the date properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ability to use the mask attribute in html grids was added in CF9. To get it to work on dates you also have to specify type=date

```
<cfgridcolumn mask="m/d/Y" type="date" ... >
```

Comment: So if thats the answer you were looking for you can accept :-) Need all the rep I can get !

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an html cfgrid, you need to use the formats found in the Ext JS Date class.  NOT the date format for Flash.

Here is a link [to the Ext JS Date class](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/?class=Date)

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfgridcolumn ... mask="mm/dd/yy">
```

[source](http://www.webmasterkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/coldfusion-flash/467/Date-format-in-CFGRID)

Comment: That is not working. I am pretty sure mask only works on flash grids. I am using an HTML grid.